# Three dots at the end of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I know how to add Ellipsized TextView in ListView item as the following code

```
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxEms="20"
    android:ellipsize="end"
```

What i want is adding three dots at the end of listView as indication for reaching the last item in the listView. Check the link below to see what i want to achieve.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/69hpe6z112p0wa3/example.png?dl=0

Note: The items in the ListView are populated from database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a static view of 3 dots and add as footer to your List View as

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: i'm getting this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.
i created Linear layout called footer_layout and added textview with three dots.. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I removed ActivityContext and it worked, @Zubair Akber Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add footer view and create a the layout as you wish to display there at the end of your list.

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

If you want to display it at the end of your last item than this approach is useful but if you want to display it all the time at the end of your list than you can add the footer view in your layout below the listview in your xml file